# poll(2) does not return when there is data ready

Tags: c++, sockets

I am attempting to write a socket abstraction in C++. I am using the poll() system call to wait for data to become ready for reading. However, when I run my program, poll() never returns if I have it set to indefinitely poll, even if I send the socket data.

Here is a simple program to illustrate my problem. I am compiling it on OSX with this line: `clang++ -g -Wall -pedantic -std=c++0x -stdlib=libc++ pollTest.cpp -o pollTest`. I am using the `nc` program to set up a listening socket for the program to connect to. When I run this, the poll() call hangs forever, never returning due to data being ready to read.

```
#include <poll.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

void connectSocket(int& fd, std::string hostname, std::string service) {
  struct addrinfo hints, *res, *res0;
  int error;
  int s;
  memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
  hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
  hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
  error = getaddrinfo(hostname.c_str(), service.c_str(), &hints, &res0);
  if (error) {
    throw error;
  }
  s = -1;
  for (res = res0; res; res = res->ai_next) {
    s = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype,
                res->ai_protocol);
    if (s < 0) {
      continue;
    }

    if (connect(s, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen) < 0) {
      close(s);
      s = -1;
      continue;
    }

    break;  /* okay we got one */
  }

  if (s < 0) {
    throw s;
  }
}

int main() {
  int socketFileDescriptor = -1;
    connectSocket(socketFileDescriptor, "localhost", "9999");

  pollfd socketPolls[1];
  socketPolls[0].fd = socketFileDescriptor;
  socketPolls[0].events = POLLIN | POLLPRI | POLLRDBAND | POLLRDNORM;
  poll(socketPolls, 1, -1);
  std::cerr << socketPolls[0].revents;
}
```

Any ideas on why this is happening? I feel as if I have read the documentation well, and am using the system calls correctly. (I didn't do error checking in this example program, but I do in my project). Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `connectSocket`, you never set `fd` to anything, so in `main`, `socketFileDescriptor` remains `-1` and `poll` won't find any data on the socket. You probably meant to unify `s` and `fd`. That said, I think you'd be better off returning the file descriptor rather than using a reference.

Comment: Right, silly mistake. Poll does return after fixing that... makes me breath easier at least, knowing that it's my code that's broken and not someone elses.

Shouldn't poll have returned anyways though, with the POLLNVAL flag set? Since I was using -1 as the descriptor?

Comment: @Chris: Surprisingly, my system's man page didn't document this, but [the POSIX specification for `poll`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/poll.html) says that “If the value of `fd` is less than 0, `events` shall be ignored, and `revents` shall be set to 0 in that entry on return from `poll()`.”